# Plot band not limited to xAxis, draws for the whole graph

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I am trying to create a plotband that is limited to only one pane. My chart is datetime chart with multiple panes bound to one xAxis. What I am trying to do is to add plotband for a single pane, so that it does not cover the whole chart. But my code yields this result: *(I have just added the plot band on the first graph to test)*

[image]

```
const option = {
    labels: {
        align: "right",
        x: -3
    },
    title: {
        text: tagName,
        style: {
            color: colors[checkedTagNames.indexOf(tag)],
            fontWeight: "500",
            fontSize: "1em",
            fontFamily: "monospace"
        },
        useHTML: true
    },
    top: top * index + "%",
    height: (1 / tagOrder.length) * 100 + "%",
    lineWidth: 2,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    offset: index % 2 === 0 ? 0 : 40,
    name: tag
};

// const plotBands = [

// ];

const plotBandOption =
    index === 0
        ? [
                {
                    // mark the weekend
                    color: "rgba(232, 48, 48, 0.38)",
                    from: moment(tagData[1 + index * 10].timestamp).valueOf(),
                    to: moment(tagData[3 + index * 10].timestamp).valueOf()
                }
          ]
        : [];

const xOption = {
    type: "datetime",
    top: top * index + "%",
    height: (1 / tagOrder.length) * 100 + "%",
    name: "x" + tag,
    // visible: true,
    plotBands: plotBandOption,
    linkedTo: 0,
    lineWidth: 0,
    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    lineColor: "transparent",
    minorTickLength: 0,
    tickLength: 0,
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    }
};

const seriesOption = {
    type: "line",
    name: tag,
    yAxis: index + 1,
    data: extractData(tagData),
    zoneAxis: "x",
    zones: testZones,
    color: colors[index % 10],
    step: true,
    dataGrouping: { enabled: false },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormatter: function() {
            const color = colors[index] ? colors[index] : "";
            const unit = checkedTags[index] ? checkedTags[index].engUnit : "";

            return (
                '<span style="color:' +
                color +
                '">' +
                this.series.name +
                "</span>: <br/> <strong>" +
                +this.y.toFixed(3) +
                " " +
                unit +
                "</strong>"
            );
        }
    }
};

chart.addAxis(option, false, false);
chart.addAxis(xOption, true, false);
chart.addSeries(seriesOption);
```

Comment: Not sure how to format the first part of the code, used the "code format" tool but it won't format. It has 4 indents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create separate xAxis with plotLines for every series and leave only one axis visible.

```
yAxis: [{
  height: '40%',
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  labels: {
    enabled: false
  },
}, {
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  labels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  height: '40%',
  top: '60%'
}],
xAxis: [{
  labels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  tickLength: 0,
  lineWidth: 0,
  plotLines: [{
    value: 1,
    width: 1,
    color: 'blue'
  }],
  height: '40%'
}, {
  top: '60%',
  height: '40%',
  plotLines: [{
    value: 4,
    width: 1,
    color: 'red'
  }],
}]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kspfu6rb/

Another solution would be to use Highcharts.SVGRenderer to create lines which imitate plotLines.

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer

Comment: That's what I am doing. My problem is that the plotBand still render on the whole graph and not limited to the assigned x-axis.

Comment: Can you prepare some minimal live example? It works fine in my case.

Comment: @Duy, do you use Highstock? It looks like there is a bug with plotLines and plotBands. I reported this problem here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8630
For now you can use SVGRenderer: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uyzwk9ho/

Comment: Yeah this is Highstock, can this be done dynamically ? I am dependent on adding the plotBand after a fetch of data, with the axes and series.

Comment: Yes, you can use SVGRenderer dynamically.

Comment: Plot lines in my example are assigned to xAxis, you have to only specify xAxis(pane) and value on xAxis, can also adapt this solution to your case. Here you can find an example with dynamic use: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ow6z2v89/